# How do I add a derived class?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

How would I go about adding 2 classes when one is a base and the other is derived?

Should I add an Employee(base) class then under Inherit the Receptionist(derived) class?

Comment: You can look at `implements` in VBA have `clsEmployee` as a base and implement it in `clsReceptionist`

Comment: I would suggest that a "receptionist" and an "employee" are two different things. A receptionist is a role and an employee is a person. You could have a contractor who is a receptionist. You could have an employee who is the receptionist on Monday to Wednesday, but is a Payroll Officer on Thursday and Friday.